# Explanation of PHP class members visibility and inheritance

Tags: php

Consider the following snippet:

```
Class A {

    private $a = 'foo';

    public function F() {
        return $this->a;
    }

}

Class B extends A {

    private $a = 'bar';

}

echo (new B)->F();
```

The result is `foo`. Well, it's a fait accompli that php works this way. But I wonder why. If in parent's method `F()` declaration I use  pseudo-variable `$this`, it refers to object context. So when I call child inherited method `F()` `$this` variable means current instance of `B` with `private $a = 'bar'`, doesn't it?

**Update**
Thanks  AbraCadaver for your reply. 
One circumstance is still unclear for me: if `$this` variable is an object of B during call of `F()`, how can it access parent's private member? 
Did I understand correctly that `$this` within parent's method implementation is something similar to:

```
  public function F(B $obj) {
    return $obj->a;
}
```

So interpreter checks property visibility from parent class and in case of private scope it subsitutes `B $obj` for `A $obj`

Comment: You want `protected`: _Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes._ **Members declared as private may only be accessed by the class that defines the member.** http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Question is not about using `protected`. Question is why php ignores `private` variable defined in a child class.

Comment: @u_mulder: Because child class can't override a private property.  So yes, it is about protected if you want it to work.

Comment: @u_mulder `ignores private variable defined in a child class`? `F()` is public so Class B can call it. `F()` is merely returning the value of it's class's private member.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I read your answer and satisfied with it, thanks)

Answer (score 1):

From [PHP: Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php):

> Members declared
>   protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by
>   inherited and parent classes. Members declared as private may only be
>   accessed by the class that defines the member.

In your example, regardless of the object being of class `B`, class `A` cannot access a `private` property of another class.

Also, if `B` has a protected property, that cannot override the class `A` property because it is `private`.

Both your example and the following yield `foo`:

```
Class A {

    private $a = 'foo';

    public function F() {
        return $this->a;
    }
}

Class B extends A {

    protected $a = 'bar';

    public function F() {
        return parent::F();
    }
}    
echo (new B)->F();
```

However, if class `A` is also `protected` then it can be overridden by class `B` and class `A` has access to the property in class `B`.

Yields `bar`:

```
Class A {

    protected $a = 'foo';

    public function F() {
        return $this->a;
    }
}

Class B extends A {

    protected $a = 'bar';

    public function F() {
        return parent::F();
    }
}
echo (new B)->F();
```